# How to remove angular watcher from directive element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive that looks like this:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function($compile,$document){
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:{
        },
        link: link, 
    };  
    return directive; 

    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        var template_html = "<div id=\"popup\">{{popupTitle}}</div>";
        var template = angular.element(template_html);

        element.bind('click', function(){
                if(!$("#popup").is(':visible')){
                    var $popup = $compile(template)(scope);
                    $document.find('body').append($popup);
                }else{
                    $("#popup").remove();
                }
            });

        template.remove();

    }
});
```

The code works fine showing up and removing the popup element when clicking on `mydirective`. But, the problem is everytime when the element shows & hide, the angular watcher is just keep on increasing. The number of watcher increase is depending on the number of binding in `template_html`.

How can I get those watcher to be removed when popup is removed so that watchers will not accumulate increase over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried destroy the scope inside the else block when the popup is being removed?

```
    element.bind('click', function(){
        if(!$("#popup").is(':visible')){
            var $popup = $compile(template)(scope);
            $document.find('body').append($popup);
        }else{
            $("#popup").remove();
            scope.$destroy();
        }
    });
```

To create a new scope you could do something like

```
var popupScope;
element.bind('click', function(){
    if(!$("#popup").is(':visible')){
        popupScope = $scope.$new();
        var $popup = $compile(template)(popupScope);
        $document.find('body').append($popup);
    }else{
        $("#popup").remove();
        popupScope.$destory();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `scope.$destroy();` destroy everything. The bindings won't work again when it show again.

Comment: Ahh hrmm that would be a problem. Can you create a new scope for your popup and then destroy that scope when the popup closes?

Comment: Can you please show an example for my understanding how that can be done? Thanks.

Comment: Edited answer to create a new scope instead of just destroy the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Store your `watcher` in your controller as a variable:

```
var myWatcher = $scope.$watch(......
```

And make sure your controller is accessible from your directive, then you can call `myWatcher()` which will unbind your watcher since calling `watch` will return an unbound function.